Understanding the Use of cattle-unauthenticated ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding for RANCHER
After running an EKS hardening program, I encountered a vulnerability related to the cattle-unauthenticated ClusterRole and its associated ClusterRoleBinding. The program advised against binding clusterroles to anonymous or unauthenticated groups.
The cattle-unauthenticated ClusterRole appears to be essential for Rancher's access to Kubernetes. Could you please explain why this specific ClusterRole is used and its necessity for Rancher's operations?
ClusterRole (cattle-unauthenticated):
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cattle-unauthenticated
  resourceVersion: '187854'
  uid: 58b45e53-6ffc-417c-8e19-27fdc771390a
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - management.cattle.io
    resourceNames:
      - first-login
      - ui-pl
      - ui-banners
      - ui-brand
      - ui-favicon
    resources:
      - settings
    verbs:
      - get

ClusterRoleBinding (cattle-unauthenticated):
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cattle-unauthenticated
  resourceVersion: '223658'
  uid: d17330f0-c2e1-42e6-a889-b666a822fd60
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cattle-unauthenticated
subjects:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: Group
    name: system:unauthenticated

